# How to conditionally evaluate sections of code with knitr

Tags: r, knitr

I use knit files (.Rnw) to develop my R code and analyses. At some stage I want to spin this off into an R code file that our users can run from the command line using Rscript etc.

When I convert the code to an R script I usually need to add opt parsing and other stuff I don't use when coding a Rnw file.

However I would like to document all that other stuff during my development of the Rnw file so everything is on one place, and I can then use knitr::purl(f) to create the basic R file at the end.

Is there a way that I could include code such as this:

```
# Set up the command line arguments
spec = matrix(c(
    'filename', 'f', 1, "character",
    'help'   , 'h', 0, "logical"
), byrow=TRUE, ncol=4);
opt = getopt(spec);

#get the script name (only works when invoked with Rscript).
self = get_Rscript_filename();
```

in the knitr file and set a condition so that it isn't parsed whenever I am knitting the file to create a pdf ?

Pete